# Export data to an existing excel worksheet

Tags: wpf, export-to-excel

I would like to know if i can change the below code to open to an existing worksheet rather than creating a new one each time? I have a wpf application.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open an exsiting workbook rather than creating a new one.

```
this.Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\YourPath\YourWorkbook.xls",
missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,missing, missing);
```

This [msdn article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306023) covers making changes to a worksheet.

Comment: Awesome that works great. :) Not is it possible just to define a specific row (based on the contact ID that is currently showing)?

Comment: yup you can do that, have a look at the msdn link above, it gives some very detailed examples of exactly that.